# SSH hangs (on Raspberry Pi B)

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi

I'm having trouble connecting to my Pi B via SSH. After entering the password, the shell simply hangs - no error message, no prompt on the pi. Can't kill ssh with `Ctrl+C` either.

Pinging the pi works, pi itself also runs fine. Tried to connect from my laptop running debian jessie, also tried JuiceSSH from my Android phone. All devices are in the same LAN.

I can fix it by rebooting the pi, but after a couple of days (I haven't found out a specific time frame yet), the same problem occurs. It seems to be related to [this Post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/344863/ssh-new-connection-begins-to-hang-not-reject-or-terminate-after-a-day-or-so-on) from 2 years ago, since the client side login hangs on the same command and displays the same characteristics. The only suggested fix (other than rebooting) didn't help.

[This Post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/12471/raspberry-pi-hangs-on-ssh-but-gives-feedback-from-a-telnet-terminal) seems to describe the same problem, for different reasons though. He doesn't even get to a password prompt. Most comments suggest either a client side problem or not having ssh enabled. Both is not the case here, as I can establish a ssh connection after a reboot without changing anything on the client side.

Here's the ouput of `ssh -vvv pi@192.168.0.20` on the client side:

```
chris@chris-laptop:~$ ssh -vvv pi@192.168.0.20
OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5, OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.20 [192.168.0.20] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/chris/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/chris/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/chris/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/chris/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/chris/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/chris/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/chris/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/chris/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.168.0.20" from file "/home/chris/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/chris/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: setup umac-64@openssh.com
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr umac-64@openssh.com none
debug2: mac_setup: setup umac-64@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr umac-64@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA f2:ff:64:a7:06:a5:b7:16:0c:b8:5a:f8:62:18:39:21
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.168.0.20" from file "/home/chris/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/chris/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host '192.168.0.20' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/chris/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/chris/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/chris/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/chris/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/chris/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/chris/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/chris/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/chris/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/chris/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/chris/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/chris/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/chris/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/chris/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
pi@192.168.0.20's password: 
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 192.168.0.20 ([192.168.0.20]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env XDG_VTNR
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AGENT_PID
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env GPG_AGENT_INFO
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env XDG_MENU_PREFIX
debug3: Ignored env VTE_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT
debug3: Ignored env WINDOWID
debug3: Ignored env GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env SESSION_MANAGER
debug3: Ignored env USERNAME
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env DESKTOP_SESSION
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug1: Sending env LANG = de_DE.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env GDM_LANG
debug3: Ignored env GDMSESSION
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SEAT
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env XDG_DATA_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
debug3: Ignored env WINDOWPATH
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env XAUTHORITY
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
```

Excerpt from /var/log/auth.log:

```
Sep  2 17:14:30 pi-fp3k sshd[6595]: Accepted password for pi from 192.168.0.94 port 58653 ssh2
Sep  2 17:14:30 pi-fp3k sshd[6595]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user pi by (uid=0)
```

Before and after that are only cronjobs, which is interesting, since I tried connecting multiple times around that time from different devices, all showing the hang.

I've also checked memory usage over a period of 24h, and 300MB+ of RAM are constantly available. This is what I expected, since the only two user programs running on the pi shouldn't generate anywhere near enough data to fill 512MB of RAM.

EDIT: I have no idea what changed, but the ssh connection hasn't died on me in quite a while now. Not really a solution to this problem, so I'll leave this open.

Comment: I have the same issue. I tried installing mosh, and still not working. It is intermittent - sometimes there is an issue and sometimes it functions fine. Nothing in the logs.  It's not processing .profile or .bashrc (I put echo's in the first lines of them) - I get the echo's when it's working. So somewhere between authentication being successful and whatever comes next it's hanging. Running Jessie on a Pi2.

Comment: And to add another detail. I can log into my mysql server, and see my motion cam video, while still not being able to ssh. So it's not a networking issue. It's something specific to what ssh is doing.

Comment: One more comment. This never happened over 2 years running wheezy - seems to have been introduced with jessie.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the final line of the question is an edit that indicates this problem cleared up on its own. So this is too broad and not reproducible as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would connect RPi directly (cross-over) cable with my pc or laptop and use wireshark/tcpdump to analyze network traffic, you will definetely see where the problem is.

Also try to connect to ssh locally from RPi if it is not on application level. This way you can debug if it is related to network or application.